# ADF radio button default selection

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a scenario where I need to apply default selection on one radio button item where radio button list is being populated from a data binding(of static data) and the data control is from a bean class.

```
 <af:selectOneRadio value="#{bindings.si_DmndType.inputValue}"
                 required="#{bindings.si_DmndType.hints.mandatory}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.si_DmndType.hints.tooltip}" id="sor1"
                   layout="horizontal" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.si_DmndType.items}" id="si1"/>
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.si_DmndType.validator}"/>
   </af:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default value for si_DmndType attribute  - in your view object.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but can you please help me where I can set the default attribute for radio button list. Basically there is a static list that contains 2 values 'Male','Female'.Now inside(view object) attribute tab I have a variable say Gender and have LOV from current view object and I am not able to find a place where I can set the default value.

Comment: Check this blog: http://jdeveloperfaq.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/faq-35-how-to-set-default-values-for.html

Comment: Tried using the given link but no luck! I am using jdevloper 12c and found the options inside VO to set the default value for the attribute 'SttsList'(that contains lov from static list). The static list has values 'Registered', 'Cancelled'. Now I have set 'Registered' as literal (tried using single/double quotes & 0,1,2) but during runtime the radio button remains deselected. Pls see image here http://postimg.org/image/j50c3x4ap/

Comment: I see "0" as default value. You should use the Code value from the static list  - "Registered', if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I have tried using all possible options here e.g. 'Registered', 'Cancelled', '0','1' but still no luck. The radio button in UI is still not coming in selected mode.

Comment: what do you see if you run your application module in BC Tester?

Comment: I was able to fix the same by making changes inside respective pageDef.xml file ->  selecting the variable and updating the DefaultValue attribute of the variable. Basically for static data source(for bean data control) I need to manually insert DefaultValue which is typically not required when you choose from a VO source. Thanks a lot for your guidance and support.

Answer (score 0):

For a bean data control, when I have static values for it I need to go at pageDef.xml file -> selecting the variable and updating the DefaultValue attribute of the variable. Basically for a static data source(for bean data control) I need to manually insert DefaultValue which is typically not required when you choose from a Value Object i.e. VO.[image: adf selection of default radio using bean data control]